# How to know if FragmentManager's back stack popped anything?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to know if anything got popped of when I called `getFragmentManager().popBackStack()`. How can I find this out?

I'm using `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`.

---

## What I tried

#### Way 1: return value

In the documentation for [android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.popBackStack()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack()), it says:

> Pop the top state off the back stack. Returns true if there was one to pop, else false.

So according to that, it should work like this:

```
boolean popped = getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

But this doesn't work because the return value of `popBackStack()` is `void`.

Is this either a bug in their code or in their documentation?

#### Way 2: back stack count

I tried to calculate from `getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()` if anything was popped:

```
int countBefore = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
int countAfter = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

boolean popped = countAfter != countBefore;
```

But this also doesn't work because of how `popBackStack()` works:

> This function is asynchronous -- it enqueues the request to pop, but
>   the action will not be performed until the application returns to its
>   event loop.

So this means that both calls to `getBackStackEntryCount()` give me the same number.

---

## Questions

1. How can I find out if anything was popped?
2. What I described in way 1: Is either a bug in Android's code or in Android's documentation?
3. If it's a bug: How can I tell them, that there's something mixed up? (I'm asking this because once I already tried to fix a mistake in their Android documentation but until today they never merged my [pull request](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/pull/140))

Comment: Way 1 don't return something cause this function is asynchronous, if you wanted it to do it synchronous and return something you should call popBackStackImmediate that returns a boolean

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStackImmediate()

Comment: I have tried this once few days back. When I did it and deploy in my phone, it just released my fragment but didn't add any previous one, this may be because I replaced it earlier. But you may try this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question:** How can I find out if anything was popped?

There are two methods for popping back stack:

- `void popBackStack()`

> Pop the top state off the back stack. This function is asynchronous -- it enqueues the request to pop, but the action will not be performed until the application returns to its event loop.

- `boolean popBackStackImmediate()`

> Like `popBackStack()`, but performs the operation immediately inside of the call. This is like calling `executePendingTransactions()` afterwards without forcing the start of postponed Transactions.

The latter one seems like the one you were looking for.

Alternatively you could [addOnBackStackChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#addOnBackStackChangedListener(android.app.FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener)) in `onStart` and unregister it in `onStop` if you need to observe changes at all times.

---

**Question:** What I described in way 1: Is either a bug in Android's code or in Android's documentation?

Quick glance in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) reveals both methods with appropriate description. [Support library](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html) looks intact as well. This was probably an oversight on your part.

EDIT: Ok, I glanced too quickly. It does say "Pop the top state off the back stack. **Returns true if there was one to pop, else false.** This function is asynchronous [...]". This is of course wrong.

---

**Question:** If it's a bug: How can I tell them, that there's something mixed up?

GitHub repo is only a mirror. The Android dev team does not go there and merge pull requests. If you wish to contribute, use AOSP gerrit. More info here: https://source.android.com/source/contributing

Alternatively you can file a bug report here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues

Comment: Yes, you are right `popBackStackImmediate()` is the method I was looking for. But the documentation of the support library must be wrong then. Because it says there and I quote "Returns true if there was one to pop, else false."

Comment: `popBackStack` is supposed to of type void because it's asynchronous, I understand that. But this doesn't change the fact that the documentation of this method is wrong then, right?

Comment: Yeah, I finally noticed it too. You're right, there is a mistake.

Comment: Okay, so we are on the same page now. Maybe just a copy-paste mistake.